# How to get the change details using commit ID

Tags: git, gerrit

I want to retrieve change details [ at least for TOT commit ] like commit id, branch , owner without cloning that repo locally. I know only revision i.e SHA ID/commit ID , branch name and repo name. Is there any way I can get the commit details?? I am using gerrit version 2.2. 
     I tried ssh query :

```
ssh -p port server-name  gerrit query  project:project_name commit:<commit_ID/SHA ID>
```

I am getting the results for only those changes which are merged through gerrit i.e. it is showing me results only for those changes which were uploaded on gerrit for review,not for those which were pushed directly bypassing gerrit reviews.

Comment: is there any online git repo browser integrated into gerrit?

Comment: Yes, but i want to use this in script.

Comment: maybe the git browser has an API, which one you have?